# Is it possible to assign function hooks to game objects, e.g. run function on init, death, etc?

Tags: javascript, screeps

I haven't found any way to assign hooks to anything, and if I could it would be very useful. Also, how can I check whether a game object still exists? (i.e. hasn't died of age, and wasn't destroyed by an enemy.)

Answer (score 4):

If you mean via API - not possible yet. But you can change your current state and compare it to memorized previous state of the objects. For example, if some creep name in `Memory` still presents, but it is gone in `Game.creeps`, then something happened.

```
for(var i in Game.creeps) {
    var creep = Game.creeps[i];
    creep.memory.lastSeenAt = {x: creep.pos.x, y: creep.pos.y};
}

for(var i in Memory.creeps) {
    if(!Game.creeps[i]) {
        console.log("Oops! Something happened with a creep "+creep.name+" at "+
            Memory.creeps[i].lastSeenAt.x+","+Memory.creeps[i].lastSeenAt.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there currently any way to check for death without worst-case iterating through all the creeps in the game?

Comment: Not yet, but we are thinking on some kind of events storage. We may add it later I hope. Iterating through creeps is not really CPU-consuming operation though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my use case :

1. Count the number of hostiles (N) in the current room
2. Count the number of alive guards (C)
3. If C < N then build another guard

After a while, when using the `Room.find(Game.MY_CREEPS)`, I'll get dead guards aswell. Having to filter them all the time is really painfull, and the global `Memory` continues to list them. Is there a way to remove dead creeps from the global `Memory` object ?

[EDIT]
Found this, hope it will help.

```
for(var i in Memory.creeps) {
    if(!Game.creeps[i]) {
        delete Memory.creeps[i];
    }
}
```

I run it at the beginning of each tick

Answer (score 1):

I forked the script-samples repository and made my own events handling code - https://github.com/pineapplemachine/script-samples/tree/master/hooks

Using that script you can assign initialization, update, and destruction methods to events rather than having to handle things more obtusely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The API seems to be focused on developing code for the main game loop, like   writing code inside a `while(true)`. But you can make your creeps do something before they die, for example.

I've created a guard module (just like the harvester module you create on the tutorial). The code below should work:

```
module.exports = function (creep) {
    if(creep.hits<=100) { Game.spawns.Spawn1.createCreep([Game.ATTACK, Game.ATTACK, Game.TOUGH, Game.TOUGH, Game.MOVE], "guard2", {role:"guard"}); }

    var targets = creep.room.find(Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS);
    if(targets.length) {
        creep.moveTo(targets[0]);
        creep.attack(targets[0]);
    } else{
        creep.moveTo(Game.spawns.Spawn1);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this situation, would the conditional "if(creep.hits<=0)" be a valid way to check if the creep has died?

Comment: Good question, I will check this and reply soon

Comment: I've created a guard module (updated the answer) and for some reason "if(creep.hits<=hit_threshold)" doesn't work.

Comment: `creep.hits <= 0` is not possible, dead creeps are removed from the game immediately.

Comment: Allright, but it works with a higher threshold. Turns out I ran out of energy on my first try so the Game wasn't generating more creeps.

Comment: What about if(!creep.hits), or try{var i=creep.hits;}catch(e){is_dead=true;} ?